# Trying to check the friendly OS name of a different workstation

Tags: c#, operating-system

I am trying to find the friendly OS name of a different workstation from my workstation. This occurred when I used:

```
var name = (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
                        select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).FirstOrDefault();
```

it is returning my workstation's OS name. Can you please suggest me a better way to find out.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementscope?view=netframework-4.7.2). Note you have to provide the name of the other computer (in WMI format) and possible also credentials required to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.DirectoryServices to search on the directory 'WinNT' you can read more about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.path?view=netframework-4.7.2

**example solution** - adding names to a list

```
// create list to add the names to
var pcnames = new List<string>();
// establish the domains in the local network
var directory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
// iterate through the children
foreach (DirectoryEntry workstation in directory.Children)
{
  pcnames.Add(workstation.Name)
}
```